# pnpm rome init throw result.error when is installed Correctly

Tags: compiler-errors, create-react-app, linter, pnpm, rome

Hello i installed [Rome](https://rome.tools/) following the documentation after do:

`pnpm add --save-dev --save-exact rome`

it's show me that is installed correctly so i run `pnpm rome init` and then i have this error by console:

```
/opt/app/node_modules/.pnpm/rome@12.0.0/node_modules/rome/bin/rome:37
                throw result.error;
                ^

Error: spawnSync /opt/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@rometools+cli-linux-x64@12.0.0/node_modules/@rometools/cli-linux-x64/rome ENOENT
    at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1119:20)
    at Object.spawnSync (node:child_process:847:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/app/node_modules/.pnpm/rome@12.0.0/node_modules/rome/bin/rome:21:42)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1196:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawnSync /opt/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@rometools+cli-linux-x64@12.0.0/node_modules/@rometools/cli-linux-x64/rome',
  path: '/opt/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@rometools+cli-linux-x64@12.0.0/node_modules/@rometools/cli-linux-x64/rome',
  spawnargs: [ 'init' ]
}
```

I tried installing rome again but doesn't work. I tried using NPM only and still the same error. I don't know what's happening this .

I only want to use Rome in my CRA Project. I'm using Docker whit the image: node:16.20-alpine

I will be very helpful if someone help me, thanks. Have a nice day